# libusb: error [op_open] getcap failed in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, libusb

I am running into trouble calling `libusb_open` in C++ on Linux (running on Raspberry Pi but virtualized to x86 using Exagear).

I can find a device using `libusb_get_device_list` but it appears translating a device to a device handler using `libusb_open` is causing problems, even though it returns a 0 (success), however no further commands work. It is giving me the error:

```
libusb: error [op_open] getcap failed (22)
```

**UPDATE**

A little bit of digging has revealed that the following command is producing the error (within libusb):

```
r = ioctl(hpriv->fd, IOCTL_USBFS_GET_CAPABILITIES, &hpriv->caps);
```

where `IOCTL_USBFS_GET_CAPABILITIES` is `_IOR('U', 26, __u32)`. Digging has revealed that `error 22` from `ioctl` is an invalid argument. I'm still trying to unpick this, but any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are your linux/libusb versions? Can you post the complete, runnable example?

Comment: Code: http://pastebin.com/S3f7ykAj building using `g++ -o test test.cpp -Wall -lusb-1.0`, Linux is 4.4.38-v7+ Debian. libusb is 1.0.19-1. Hope this helps! EDIT: line 95

Comment: My first thought was to check whether the version of the Linux kernel used supports `IOCTL_USBFS_GET_CAPABILITIES`. According to `usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.38-v7+/include/uapi/linux/usbdevice_fs.h` in linux-headers-4.4.38-v7+_4.4.38-v7+-2_armhf.deb **the ioctl is supported**. The next most common reason i can think of for `ioctl()` returning `EINVAL` (i.e. -22) is a ***32bit/64bit mismatch between the user-space app and the Linux kernel***. This [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9883441/319204) explains it well.

Comment: Do you have permissions to access the USB device?  Does the call succeed when run from root?  That would point you in the right direction, because if it runs under root, you need to grant your account the capabilities to access USB ports.

Comment: Is the hpriv->fd valid?

Comment: As the error states, check the arguments. It is either hpriv (then implicitly fd and caps), hpriv->fd or hpriv->caps. For address of the member, it would be more explicit to use '&(hpriv->caps)' to avoid thinking of operator precedence, ioctrl is overloaded enough to allow the wrong argument.